# Python Firefox Selenium Load Profile

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I tried  many combinations of Geckodrive,Selenium and Python but i could not achieved to load Firefox profile what i need.It loads the default profile.
The lastest code is below and I opened an issue on github Selenium page but there is still no solution.There are some solutions about Java but I am not able to bind it in Python.A temp file created on temp folder which includes profile data and cookies.That mean selenium does not use any profile's cookies and other configurations

Any solutions will be apprecited.

Geckodrive version:0.23
Selenium 3.14
Python 3.7
Firefox 61

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

fp = FirefoxProfile('C:\\Users\\<USER>\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\ji8rbij6.test')
fp.update_preferences()
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
```

Thanks in advance

PS. I tried this code block in 3 different computer because of being able to have a problem on my own computer

Comment: test your profile, run command or create shortcut with Target `"<your_dir>\firefox.exe" -P test -no-remote`

Comment: Thanks for helping @ewwink what shoul i see when run this command? It opens a  new firefox window.

Comment: it should open firefox with `test` profile, it is returned firefox with expected profile? FYI, your code is fine it open selected profile in my windows

Comment: OMG! Code is fine and works fine on your machine OMG I am in trouble now that s mean the problem is more than code now! Selenium opens firefox window what it sets on default firefox.My aim for using firefox profile is that Selenium can open webdriver more quicker and do not create temp profile instance file in temp folder.

Comment: maybe you have multiple `test` profile, check in profile dir or create other profile with unique name

Comment: @ewwink No,I checked it many times.I have 3 profiles and all of them have unique name.I tried many solutions but i didnot get what i expect.Because of not able to choose the profile what i want,it creates many instances of firefox in temp almost 10 Gb.I am in the middle of a project and i am totally stuck.

Comment: @ewwink What is your working env ? Python,selenium,geckodriver,Firefox versions.I may test it with that configurations

Comment: Python 2.7.13 & 3.7.0, selenium 3.141.0, geckodriver 0.23.0, Firefox 64 dev edition

Comment: @ewwink thank you for paying atteniton

Comment: I'm woriking with Java and using this: @BeforeClass
public static void setUpClass() {
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
ProfilesIni allProfiles = new ProfilesIni(); 
FirefoxProfile selenium_profile = allProfiles.getProfile("selenium_profile");
options.setProfile(selenium_profile);
options.setBinary("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\pburgr\\Desktop\\selenium-tests\\FF_driver_0_23\\geckodriver.exe");
driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
}

Comment: @pburgr thanks for answer.Selenium works stable with java but unfortunately,it isnot as stable as with Python.Thanks for taking time and putting a solution.I

Answer (score 0):

This exact setup works as expected for me (windows10) and I'm able to load custom firefox profiles.
Firefox: 88.0.1
Geckodriver: 0.30.0 ([geckodriver releases](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)
Python: 3.8.10
robotframework-selenium2library: 3.0.0
robotframework-seleniumlibrary: 6.0.0

```
import SeleniumLibrary
from selenium import webdriver
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn
def create_profile(self)
    fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
    fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
    fp.set_preference("browser.download.panel.shown", False)
    fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir","**provide_download_dir_here**")
    fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile", 
    "application/zip,application/octet-stream, application/x-zip-compressed, 
    multipart/x-zip,image/jpeg,application/xml,application/pdf,text/plain,text/csv, 
    */*")
    fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", 
    "application/zip,application/octet-stream, application/x-zip-compressed, 
    multipart/x-zip,image/jpeg,application/xml,application/pdf,text/plain,text/csv, 
    */*")
    fp.update_preferences()
    return fp.path
# Add the following code where you open the browser
ff = self.create_profile()   
BuiltIn().get_library_instance("SeleniumLibrary").open_browser("https://your_url","F    irefox",ff_profile_dir=ff)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32070423)

Comment: I edited my answer to include some working code sample.